# Qt - change cursor selection

Tags: android, c++, qt, cursor

I'm developing Qt application . I want to use cursor in QTextEdit  for copy or cut QString like Android's Native.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
m_messageEdit->installEventFilter(this);

eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::Gesture)
    {
        QWidget *focused = qobject_cast<QWidget *>(object);

        if (focused == m_messageEdit->viewport())
        {
            QGestureEvent* gEvent = static_cast<QGestureEvent*>(event);

            if (QGesture *gesture = gEvent->gesture(Qt::TapAndHoldGesture))
            {
                QTapAndHoldGesture *tapAndHold = static_cast<QTapAndHoldGesture*>(gesture);

                if (tapAndHold->state() == Qt::GestureFinished)
                {
                    QTextCursor cursor = m_messageEdit->textCursor();
                    cursor.beginEditBlock();
                    cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::StartOfWord);
                    cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::EndOfWord, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor);
                    cursor.endEditBlock();
                    m_messageEdit->setTextCursor(cursor);
                    connect(m_messageEdit, SIGNAL(selectionChanged()), this, SLOT(updateSelection()));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

updateSelection()
{
}
```

It was working when I started tap and hold on *QTextEdit*. it was select from start word to end of word. I want to expand selection if user changes cursor , so I called `selectionChanged()`. but I have no idea how to compare old cursor with new one or expand selection area  . Any suggestion?

EDITED : it's moving selection word automatically. I want to disable this and expand selection.